# How to expire set of redis in lua every day?

Tags: redis, lua

I am banning spider using lua script in openresty(1.13.6.2). It will probe the illegal ip and add to black list.

```
res , err = cache:sadd('black-list', ngx.var.remote_addr)
```

Now I want to make black list expire in 12:00 every day(Release ban ip). How to expire set daily?What is the proper way?This is the ban forbidden code:

```
is_black ,err = cache:sismember('black_list', ngx.var.remote_addr)
if is_black == 1 then
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
    goto label
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative: you can use `string` redis data type for saving IPs instead of `set` (for convenience in searching you can use some common part in the key, for example `black_list`; redis key can be divided by semicolon):

```
# redis cli commands
set black_list:127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 EX 3600 # expires in 1 hour
set black_list:127.0.0.2 127.0.0.2 EX 60   # expires in 1 minute 
set black_list:127.0.0.3 127.0.0.3 EX 60   # expires in 1 minute
```

In this case you can calculate (`12:00 - now`) and set `TTL (time to live)` for each IP record and they will be expired automatically in needed time without any additional actions from code.